# Metasploit error on Alpine

Tags: ruby, alpine-linux, metasploit

When I trying to run `./msfconsole` I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        9: from ./msfconsole:48:in `<main>'
        8: from ./msfconsole:48:in `require'
        7: from /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/payload_generator.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        6: from /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/payload_generator.rb:2:in `require'
        5: from /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/payload/apk.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        4: from /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/payload/apk.rb:3:in `require'
        3: from /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core.rb:44:in `require'
        1: from /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/db_manager.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/db_manager.rb:66:in `<class:DBManager>': undefined local variable or method `optionally_include_metasploit_credential_creation' for Msf::DBManager:Class (NameError)
```

But I have installed *metasploit-credential* (`gem install metasploit-credential`). I use **Alpine**, version **3.2.0** architecture is **i386 musl-linux**. How can I solve this error? Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you share what version of Alpine are you using?

Comment: Alpine version is 3.2.0

Comment: metaspolit is not shipped by default with alpine: which steps are you following to install it?
Moreover, Alpine 3.2 is quite old. You should consider to upgrade it to the latest stable, if possilbe (3.11).

Answer (score 0):

This is a receipe to have metasploit running with the last stable alpine version.

This comes from alpine-metasploit docker image I made a while ago and available here:
https://github.com/fcolista/alpine-metasploit and uses PostgreSQL DB as backend.

If you don't want to a database you can skip the PostgreSQL setup (described at point n.5) and start `mfsconsole` with `"-n"` argument (as shown in the script at point n.6), but please consider that metasploit will be slower without a DB.

**1. Use Alpine 3.11 in main and community repositories**

```
echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main" > /etc/apk/repositories
echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
```

**2. Add the needed packages**

```
apk update && \
apk add build-base ruby ruby-bigdecimal \
    ruby-bundler ruby-io-console ruby-webrick \
    ruby-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev \
    readline-dev sqlite-dev postgresql-dev \
    libpcap-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev \
    yaml-dev zlib-dev ncurses-dev autoconf \
    bison subversion git sqlite nmap \
    libxslt postgresql ncurses
```

**3. Clone the metasploit repository in `/usr/share` (adjust the dir according with your needs)**

```
cd /usr/share && \
    git clone https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework.git && \
    cd /usr/share/metasploit-framework && \
    bundle update --bundler
    bundle install
```

**4. Remove the un-needed packages**

```
apk del build-base ruby-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev \
    readline-dev sqlite-dev postgresql-dev \
    libpcap-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev yaml-dev \
    zlib-dev ncurses-dev bison autoconf \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

**5. Setup and start PostgreSQL**

```
rc-service postgresql setup && rc-service postgresql start
```

**6. Copy/paste this simple script which setup DB and starts mfsconsole.**

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/share/metasploit-framework/msfupdate

MSFUSER=${MSFUSER:-postgres}
MSFPASS=${MSFPASS:-postgres}
DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=${DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR:-localhost}

if ! [ -z "$DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR" ]; then
    # Check if user exists
    if ! [ $(psql -h $DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR -p 5432 -U postgres postgres -tAc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='$MSFUSER'") == "1" ]; then
        psql -h $DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR -p 5432 -U postgres postgres -c "create role $MSFU SER login password '$MSFPASS'"
    fi
    if ! [ $(psql -h $DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR -p 5432 -U postgres postgres -lqtA | grep "^msf|"  | wc -l) == "1" ]; then
        psql -h $DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR -p 5432 -U postgres postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE msf OWNER $MSFUSER;"
    fi

sh -c "echo 'production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: msf
  username: $MSFUSER
  password: $MSFPASS
  host: $DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR
  port: 5432
  pool: 75
  timeout: 5' > /usr/share/metasploit-framework/config/database.yml"

else
    /usr/share/metasploit-framework/msfconsole -n
fi

/usr/share/metasploit-framework/msfconsole
```

.: Francesco